# GeoRSS Reading Coordinates in FME

Tags: arcgis-online, fme-form, feature-service, georss

http://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/currentincidents.aspx

I'm looking to read this RSS feed, taking the entries, and publishing to an AGOL feature service. Using the GeoRSS reader I can see the attributes and the point locations are shown, however, I don't have a clue how to expose the attributes, form a table, create the vertex, then get this published.
I was expecting something like the Json reader where you take the element and use json schema scan.

I've read elements of the FME forum and HTML Extractor is suggested, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

FME 2021.0 has a [GeoRSS](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/georssfeaturereader.htm) reader.

Here is an example of GeoRSS working with the reader with

```
http://trafficscotland.org/rss/feeds/currentincidents.aspx
```

[image]

**For the attributes** use the [AttributeExploder](https://www.safe.com/transformers/attribute-exploder/)

And you will be able tp pull out an manipulate those Attributes

Example: With some cleanup and duplication removal.
[image]

**For Coordinates** - use the [CoordinateExtractor](https://www.safe.com/transformers/coordinate-extractor/)
[image]